# Possible to send audio files through websocket?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I am building a web application that generates a new audio file depending on the input from the user. The wav file is generated in our python backend and now I want to be able to play it to the user on the frontend. How can I do this with websockets? (which I'm already using in the application)

I have looked at several other posts here att stackoverflow but none answers my question as I'm not using Angular, Node or React. Just Javascript for frontend and python for the backend.

Comment: What connects the front end and back end? Just sockets? Would it not be easier to use a web framework?

Comment: Yes! But right now that is now how it is done. Only a websocket is connecting back and frontend. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Moving on from the position you're in, no I don't have a suggestion sorry. It seems a lot like reinventing the wheel while I would have been using Flask from the start and that can stream video [just fine](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited). But other frameworks can do it too

Comment: I will look into Flask, as it does not seem to be that hard to implement :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't do this.

- encode your audio into MP3 or OGG or whatever your target browser(s) support
- send it over the web socket to the client
- receive the data into something [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)-like

Then, depending on how you want to play things,

- [generate an object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) out of the data and pass that in as the `src` for an `<audio>` tag, *or*
- use the Web Audio API and [`decodeAudioData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) to get a buffer source you can play.

Comment: Seems interesting! I will try this, however I wonder how to send my wav file into the web socket..

Comment: If you already have code that is able to send data over a web socket, there shouldn't be anything too complicated to send audio data instead. However, I would really recommend a compressed format like OGG or Opus or whatnot instead of uncompressed WAV!

Comment: Ok! Right now we send a JSONobject through the websocket. I will try to find a midi to OGG converter, thx!

Comment: If you already have a way to get a .wav, use ffmpeg (or a wrapper library for it) to convert to .ogg.

Comment: This worked fine also with wav file! Just took some time to read the file in backend.